# How to get distinct rows based on selected columns instead of all columns of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get first distinct 3 columns while the last column can have any value. If i do distinct on all columns then it gives me 8 rows. This table is dynamic so i will need distinct 3 columns and any value in the last column.

I have the following scenerio,

```
Name       Surname   Road           Pet
John       Trav     John_road       dog
Kaley      Couco    Couco_road     horse
Charlie    Sheen    Sheen_road     rabbit 
Johnny     Galecki  Galecki_road    cat 
John       Trav     John_road      donkie
Kaley      Couco    Couco_road      mouse
Charlie    Sheen    Sheen_road      goat
Johnny     Galecki  Galecki_road    pig
```

Desired result:

```
Name       Surname   Road           Pet
John       Trav     John_road       dog
Kaley      Couco    Couco_road     mouse
Charlie    Sheen    Sheen_road     rabbit 
Johnny     Galecki  Galecki_road    cat
```

I tried the solution on this link but it is not working:

[Oracle 11g SQL to get unique values in one column of a multi-column query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983202/oracle-11g-sql-to-get-unique-values-in-one-column-of-a-multi-column-query)

Please help in Oracle

Answer (score 2):

As you don't care about the last column value, a simple option is to aggregate it as

```
select name, surname, road, max(pet) 
from your_table
group by name, surname, road
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` with `partition by` first three columns:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9236081e400162d9196bb24d3e6ef012)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (
    select t.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by Name, Surname, Road order by pet) rn 
      from t)
  where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME, rOAD, PET FROM 
(
SELECT NAME, SURNAME, rOAD, PET, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, SURNAME, rOAD ORDER BY PET) RN FROM FROM TABLE_NAME
) WHERE RN=1
```